# can't invoke destroy command

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

I'm trying to close a grid and open a new one with the name of the old one, so that I can do this more times with just using one function.

```
testgrid=a_nice_grid
def sth(button):
        if button=='filter':

            testgrid.destroy()
            global testgrid
            testgrid=app_grid.addGrid(name,data)
```

with this code I get the following Error:

> File "appJar\appjar.py", line 2724, in 
>      return lambda: funcName(param)
>    File "", line 251, in sth
>      testgrid.destroy()
>    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2097, in >destroy
>      self.tk.call('destroy', self._w)
>   TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command:  application has been destroyed

How can I give a new value to the variable `testgrid`, in a similar way to my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cleanly remove a grid, you can use `app.removeGrid("<grid name>")`

See here: http://appjar.info/pythonWidgetOptions/#widget-manipulation

Then, when you add another grid, it can have the same name:

```
def press(button):
   app.removeGrid("g")
   app.addGrid("g", [["a", "b", "c"]], 0, 0)

app = gui()
app.addGrid("g", [["a", "b", "c"]])
app.addButton("PRESS", press)
app.go()
```

**NB.** when you add another widget, you'll need to specify the grid position, otherwise it'll be added beneath the button.

Answer (score 0):

`destroy()` command completely removes the widget and it cannot be reused.

Instead of adding and removing widgets, you can simply use `testgrid.grid_forget()`. This removes the widget from the User interface and can be used later. If you do not wish to the widget, you can run the commands as follows:

```
testgrid.grid_forget()
testgrid.destroy()
```